# kotlin.reflect.KClass.isInstance(value: Any?) not working

Tags: class, kotlin, reflection, instanceof

I'm trying the follow

```
"simple string"::class.isInstance(kotlin.String)
```

But it return **false**!

> I'm using
>
> "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.3.21"

The another examples also fail

```
1::class.isInstance(kotlin.Int)
true::class.isInstance(Boolean)
```

Please, help me to understand it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the API incorrectly, the `isInstance` function does the opposite check as shown in the documentation:

> Returns `true` if [value] is an instance of this class on a given platform.

The `kotlin.Int` line does not refer to a type, you miss the `::class`.

A possible solution is to flip the declaration:

```
String::class.isInstance("a string")  /// true
Int::class.isInstance(42) /// true
```

You may also compare KClass objects, e.g. `432::class == Int::class` or use KClass functions `isSubclassOf` and `isSuperclassOf`

Comment: `432::class == Int::class` it work but `Int::class.isInstance(42)` not. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`kotlin.String`, `kotlin.Int`, and `Boolean` are used as values, so they refer to [companion objects](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#companion-objects) of the corresponding classes. So the first line checks whether the `String` companion object is a `String` and correctly tells you it isn't.

Comment: I was looking for a Java's `Class#isAssignableFrom(obj)` function analog. It is interesting to spot that `kotlin.Int` means companion object, but `kotlin.Int::class` means the KClass of not (and not a KClass of the companion)

Comment: @EugenePetrenko Do you mean `Class#isAssignableFrom(Class<?>)`? That would be  https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.full/is-superclass-of.html (and nicely, there's a symmetric `isSubclassOf`).